# Uninstalling Calculator App Windows 10, Package could not be registered error

Tags: windows-10, powershell, uninstall, calculator

My Windows 10 calculator stopped working. I can't seem to re-install it using the PowerShell methods described on various Google searches. I receive 'Package could not be registered' errors.

Here's what I have been getting:

```
PS C:\Users\Paul> Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1601.49020.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF6, Package could not be registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CF6) NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] 418155ef-ce3b-0000-6dc6-81413bced101 in the Event Log or use the command line Get-AppxLog -ActivityID 418155ef-ce3b-0000-6dc6-81413bced101 At line:1 char:1 + Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Win ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Program File...ppxManifest.xml:String) [Add-AppxPackage], IOException  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand

PS C:\Users\Paul> Get-AppxPackage *windowscalculator* | Remove-AppxPackage Remove-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF6, Package could not be registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CF6) NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] 418155ef-ce3b-0001-e8c4-81413bced101 in the Event Log or use the command line Get-AppxLog -ActivityID 418155ef-ce3b-0001-e8c4-81413bced101 At line:1 char:39 + Get-AppxPackage *windowscalculator* | Remove-AppxPackage +                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Microsoft.Windo...__8wekyb3d8bbwe:String) [Remove-AppxPackage], IOException  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.RemoveAppxPackageCommand
```

Is there some way to remove the calculator app from the registry to I can re-load it through the Microsoft Store?

Comment: You need to format your question better, its nearly impossible , to tell where the command starts/ends and where the error message begins.  If you run `get-appxpackage -allusers | Select Name, PackageFullName` Is `WindowsCalculator` shown in the list?

Comment: Have you verified other UWP work, it seems odd, only the calculator would stop working.  [Windows Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/windows-calculator/9wzdncrfhvn5)

Comment: Yes, WindowsCalculator is in the list from the get-appxpackage command. It is also in my start menu. When I click it, the circle spins for a while and nothing happens.
Other UWP programs are working ok. Groove music, Weather, etc.